# Select bool representing whether or not a row's ID is within another table

Tags: mysql

Is there a way to get a bool column in a resultset using the `IN` statement?

I know I can do something like this to just select all the rows whose IDs are found in another table, and then the inverse to select those who aren't, deriving true/false from there:

```
SELECT * FROM people WHERE id IN (SELECT staff.personID FROM staff)
```

But I was hoping to just have something like:

```
SELECT
    people.*,
    (people.id IN (SELECT staff.personID FROM staff)) AS marked
FROM people
```

With the result:

```
+----+--------+--------+
| id | name   | marked |
+----+--------+--------+
| 1  | Marty  | 1      |
| 2  | Steven | 1      |
| 3  | Daniel | 0      | <--- Not found in 'staff'.
| 4  | James  | 1      |
+----+--------+--------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query should work:

```
SELECT people.*,
       (people.id IN (SELECT staff.personID FROM staff)) AS marked
FROM people;
```

I think it would be more efficient as:

```
SELECT p.*,
       (exists (SELECT 1 FROM staff s WHERE s.PersonID = p.id)) AS marked
FROM people p;
```

Comment: Hah, you're right it does work. I couldn't get your 2nd example to work, but in my case the tables are very small so efficiency shouldn't be a concern anyway. Thanks.